# bash command to get list of all hosted domains on centos server

Tags: centos, bash

How would I get list of all hosted domains on centos server using bash command. I am runing centos server. I need to fetch the list of hosted domains on that server. I can get it using plesk. but It would be handy to know the way to do this using bash

Comment: Which web server are you running?

Comment: what does it mean for a domain to be "hosted" in this context? Web servers? Mail? Anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using apache then

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -S
```

Will will dump out a description of how Apache parsed the configuration file, which should be the configured hosts.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later :-)

```
for yaml in $(ls /home/*/.cpanel/ema*.yaml -1); do sed '3q;d' $yaml|cut -d: -f1 ; done
```